# Finding the next result from a MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect, excel-match

I am trying to produce a sorted table in excel, which depend on the selected year and category.

My methodology has been to sequentially find largest values in order, within the selected year and category parameters, doing the following:

**Column E**

```
{=LARGE(IF(('Master Data'!A$1:A$500 = $B$1) * ('Master Data'!B$1:B$500 = $B$2),'Master Data'!C$1:C$500), $B10)}
```

This works fine, `$B$1$` is where I store the year, `$B$2` is where I store the category, `$B10` references a hard coded 1-25 in column `B`.

**Column F**

```
{=MATCH(E10,IF(('Master Data'!A$1:A$500 = $B$1) * ('Master Data'!B$1:B$500 = $B$2),'Master Data'!C$1:C$500),FALSE)}
```

This returns the row number of the result I need, which I then use in conjunction with `INDEX` to find related data.

The problem with this is that Match only returns the first row number, and if you have two results with the same value this clearly becomes an issue.

**Column G**

To resolve this I used an example from [dailydoseofexcel](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/11/29/finding-the-2nd-3rd-4th-match/) which looks like this:

```
=IF(F10<>F11, F11, G10+MATCH(E11,INDIRECT("'Master Data'!C"&(G10+1)&":C500"),0))
```

This works to a limited extent, for my purposes, as it is unable to take into account the year and category filter I need to apply, so I tried:

```
{=IF(F10<>F11, F11, G10+MATCH(E11,IF((INDIRECT("'Master Data'!A"&(G10+1)&":A500") = $C$2) * (INDIRECT("'Master Data'!B"&(G10+1)&":B500") = $C$3), INDIRECT("'Master Data'!C"&(G10+1)&":C500")),0))}
```

But I am just getting `#N/A` as a result.

Comment: What you want to do is sort a list but put your selected year and category on top, correct?  Do you worry about how the rest of the items are sorted?

Answer (score 0):

I think **SUMPRODUCT** may be what you are looking for:

[Charley Kyd XL Legend: Use SUMPRODUCT to get the Last item in a list](http://exceluser.com/explore/last-item-in-list.htm)

Comment: Nope, I am not looking for the last in a list, I need to find the correlating result.